# Convert JSON format in c#

Tags: asp.net, json

I Have a Json Format

```
strHTML = {"responseCode":"3001","response":"1533352425185"}
```

but i want to get only `3001` how to get it in asp.net?

Comment: error : JsonConvert does not exist when i am using                                       
                              List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(strHTML);

Comment: Public Class Test {
public string responseCode { get; set; }
public string response { get; set; }
}

Test obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(strHTML);
string responseCode = obj.responseCode;